# Smaller browser default monospace font

Tags: html, css

Let have this:

```css
.courier {
  font-family: 'Courier';
}

.monospace {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<p class="courier">Some sample text</p>
<p class="monospace">Some sample text</p>
```

Why is the default monospace font smaller? And what is the default size for `font-family: monospace;`?

Comment: Just a note: Here (in Firefox on Mac) the "Courier" CLASS  is NOT displayed with a "Courier" or even just a monospace font (instead with a serif default font, probably Times New Roman). Only if I change `font family` to `'Courier', monospace`, it IS displayed with a monospace font (but with a larger font-size, as you desribe it)

Comment: That's is weird to me. Any idea of why?

Comment: no, no idea - "Courier" is installed in my system. Maybe it has to do with the way those snippets work, emulating a browser engine (?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different browsers have different base rendering defaults. WebKit and Firefox have chosen to set a smaller base font-size for the 'monospace' font-family.

https://www.brunildo.org/test/monospace_fsize.html

Browser set these defaults to improve content readability when no developer CSS is defined.